# SQL's date function not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, date

I'm trying to use MySQLs date function in Laravel 4.2 but it doesn't seem to be working, or I'm doing something wrong...

Query:

```
[query] => select * from `activity_logs` where `user_id` = ? and date(`created_at`) = ? order by `created_at` asc

[bindings] => Array
    (
        [0] => 62731
        [1] => 2015-05-12
    )

[time] => 0.62
```

Screenshot of table: https://i.gyazo.com/1ad25c1b536be7e5f794256cb1ced1ea.png

I want to ignore the time, and just get the date. I know I'm doing something wrong but not sure what.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Not working for what? Wrong result? Exception? Or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have records created on that date. 
From the screenshot all records are created 2016 and your query is asking for 2015.

Answer (score 0):

If you just did not get the result what you expected, try this, might help for you;)

```
select * from `activity_logs` where `user_id` = ? and date_format(`created_at`, '%Y-%m-%d') = ? order by `created_at`
```